# How to fit chart and table on same page on ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In same report I have one chart and one table. How to fit chart and table on same page on ssrs?

I have already tried to increase height or I tried to change interactive height as 0 but it didn't help.

Also I have tried to put them in rectangular, when I put them in rectangular, I can not see my table.

Could you please help me about this?

Comment: You've changed the Size in the Body Properties for the report?

Comment: Can you post an image of the report preview as well as the design?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the my chart and table..

[image]

When ı click preview they show different page:

[image]

[image]